# Why does requests return an error when running through a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

There's an endpoint called **getbalance** on the [Bittrex Api](https://bittrex.com/home/api) which takes in a currency as a string and returns your current balance for that currency. When doing the request in a function,

```
balance = get_balance('BTC')
```

the request returns:

> {'message': 'INVALID_SIGNATURE',
>   'result': None,
>   'success': False}

Function:

```
def get_balance(currency):
    endpoint = '/account/getbalance'
    params = {
        'currency' : currency
    }
    return call_endpoint(endpoint, False, params)
```

call_endpoint:

```
def call_endpoint(endpoint, isPublic, params = None):
    base_url = 'https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1'
    url = (base_url + endpoint + 
       '?apikey=' + API_KEY + 
       '&nonce=' + str(time.time())).encode('utf-8')
    signature = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY, url, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
    headers = {'apisign' : signature}
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers, params=params)
    return r
```

However, if I were to request it outside of a function:

```
url = ('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getbalance' + 
    '?apikey=' + API_KEY +
    '&nonce=' + str(time.time()) +
    '&currency=BTC').encode('utf-8')
signature = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY, url, hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
headers = {'apisign' : signature}
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
```

it works.

> {'message': '',
>   'result': {'Available':
>   ...,
>   'success': True}

These two approaches have the same code, so is there something about python functions or the requests library that causes this error?

Comment: Only difference is sending params.please remove (params argument) inside function and try it out

Comment: The URLs are different in the two cases; one includes the currency, the other doesn't. That will affect the computed signature, although I don't know if that will make a difference for this particular API. (I'm assuming your call is `get_balance("BTC")` or an equivalent.)

Comment: I edited it to show the initial call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two approaches do not do the same thing.

Your `call_endpoint` function computes a signature for the headers on an input of the url WITHOUT a `currency` param, then has `requests` add in the `currency` param.

Your other snippet computes the signature on a url that contains the `currency` param.